# Why does my storage keep filling up?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, storage

I've noticed while developing an app, that my storage space keeps filling up. Repeated deployments from Android Studio seem to be slowly filling up the internal storage, as if the older iterations of the app are not getting uninstalled. I have specified a grade-aware Make (:app:uninstallAll) to attempt to alleviate this but I've had no success.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Apologies, I know this question had  lot of potential scope. Accepted answer to manually manage the app installation. Using ADB-IDEA plugin to help with this. Will do for the moment. Thanks all.

Comment: I think that this unfortunately too broad. There can be various reasons for such problems; and debugging them without having access to your whole setup is close to impossible in my eyes.

Comment: Do you have root permissions available on the device? We can peer into the private storage, if so.

Comment: @GhostCat Fair enough. Adan_SL's suggestion will suffice, and I've supplemented it with the ABD-Idea plugin.

Comment: @MeetTitan I do not. The manual route will do for the moment. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're debuggin with instant run, Android Studio makes the changes in cache, that's why the internal storage is filling up.

Try this:

1. Delete the data of the app.
2. Unninstall the app.
3. In Android Studio, Menu Build -> Build APK and install it manually.

If you are affraid that your apk is taking too much space, you can use the [APK Analyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've actually disabled instant run and the app is quite large (lots of resources). Manually managing it might work out. I'm also trying out the ABD-Idea plugin for Android Studio. I'll see how it goes. I'll comment again later.

Comment: In the link there's a guide to reduce the size of de APK. I forgot to  mention that you have to check your apis in the app, for example, in mi app i display some maps with Google Maps, an if the user haven't load the map early, it will store the map in the cache of the app and increase the size.